# Pesonalize News feed for my socia networking application

Tags: python, node.js

I am implementing a social networking App  Backend and I am using Node.js for development but in my app one feature is feed like in Instagram following and explore feed.
 I have implemented backend in node js but for a feed algorithm I use python so how to integrate python function into node and also I want to know is it a good approach to in one single application you use two different languages.I use python because in future we use some machine learning so we all know no language is better than python for machine learning.

Please explain to me what is the right way to do it